# Flask with development server and uwsgi, config.from_object()

Tags: python, flask

my problem is that my Flask app is either working with the dev server or with uwsgi. Here is my layout.

```
project/
    project/
        static/
        templates/
        helper.py
        settings.py
        server.py
    uwsgi.ini
```

The problematic line in server.py

```
app.config.from_object('project.settings') # works with uwsgi

app.config.from_object('settings') # works with dev
```

I want to start the webserver from the root directory, with "python project/server.py" or in production: uwsgi --ini uwsgi.ini

My uwsgi.ini file

```
[uwsgi]
module = project.server
....
```

Development server error with "project.settings"

```
ImportError: No module named project.settings
```

uwsgi with "settings"

```
ImportError: No module named settings
```

Is there a way to fix this without modifying PYTHONPATH or doing with try/except?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use chdir uWSGI option, you can set it to the same directory you use when you run flask from the commandline with the development server.

In your case, something like

chdir = XXX/project/project

will do the trick